# Find child and remove its parent using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm able to find the child but can not remove its parent, which is the td row

```
<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Test Information</td></tr>

$(rowHtml).find('input').parent().remove();
```

I would like the following output:

```
<tr><td>Test Information</td></tr>
```

Comment: What output are you getting and what browser?  It looks fine to me in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(rowHtml).closest('tr').find('td:first').find('input').remove();
```

I have added this code in Jsfiddle check this: http://jsfiddle.net/4E5zP/1/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close your expression

`$(rowHtml).click(function() { $(this).parent().remove();});`

Answer (score 0):

I just added a class name to the parent of the input element and remove it

```
             <tr><td class="inputTD"><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Test Information</td></tr>

                   $(rowHTML).find(".inputTD").remove().end();
```